# Countdown timer accelerating and not exact with IEnumerator

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, countdown

I'm trying to create a consistent countdown timer that will get from 1,000 to 0 in 120 seconds.

I tried to use this method:

```c#
    public IEnumerator StartCountdown()
    {
        while (scoreValue > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            scoreValue--;
        }
    }
```

but the counting down from some reason accelerates as time passes by and it reaches different minus numbers depending on the `scoreValue` value rather then stopping in 0.

For example if `scoreValue` equals 1000 it reaches -380

Comment: Add more code. Show how`scoreValue`  is declared and how you are calling `StartCountdown`. Also show where(which function) you are calling `StartCountdown` from.

Comment: You are probably calling `StartCoroutine` on this method multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments earlier, you might have listed the method many times. Which will increase at a faster rate the more times you have the method being called. You only need one StartCoroutine method with the method name. Watch the console as it counts down 1 by 1 with the code listed.
Here's the code. Everything seems to be ok.

```
float scoreValue = 1200;
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(StartCountdown());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public IEnumerator StartCountdown()
{
    while (scoreValue > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        scoreValue--;
        print("Score At " + scoreValue.ToString());
    }
}
```